# How to make particular vertical lines wider with `tabulararray` package

Tags: tables, color, tabularray

In this table

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}   
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTblrTheme{captionof}%
{%
    \DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}%
    {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
    }
}
\definecolor{nl1}{RGB}{68, 119, 160} 
\definecolor{nl2}{RGB}{102, 204, 238} 
\definecolor{nl3}{RGB}{204, 187, 68} 
\definecolor{nl4}{RGB}{238, 102,119} 

     \colorlet{l1}{nl2!70} 
     \colorlet{l2}{nl3!70} 
     \colorlet{l3}{nl4!70} 
     \colorlet{l4}{Gray!70} 
    \colorlet{lD1}{nl2!35} 
    \colorlet{lD2}{nl3!35} 
    \colorlet{lD3}{nl4!35} 
    \colorlet{lD4}{Gray!35} 



\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \footnotesize 
    \begin{talltblr}[
  theme = captionof,
caption = {Accuracy [\%]. Brown, green, blue, yellow fills indicate L1 to L4 layouts; the lighter tones of colors indicate dropout added to layout. Unfilled cells correspond to cases with ties.},
  label = {tab:ACCTAB},
note{\textdagger} = {L1, L4, L1-D, L3-D},
note{\textdaggerdbl} = {L1, L3-D}
                    ]{
    hlines, vlines,
    colspec = {Q[r] *{9}{X[c, m]}},
    colsep=1.8pt,
    row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
    row{3}  = {mode=math},
                     }
\SetCell[c=10]{c}    {Basic model}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c}
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {Ideal}
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {Simple}
                    &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {{{Complex}}}
                                &   &       \\
    & d{=}2
        & d{=}2.5
            & d{=}3 
                & d{=}2 
                    & d{=}2.5 
                        & d{=}3 
                            & d{=}2 
                                & d{=}2.5 
                                    & d{=}3 \\
4 boxes
    & \SetCell{bg=l1}   99.95
        & \SetCell{bg=lD1}  99.7
            & \SetCell{bg=lD1}  99.55
                & \SetCell{bg=lD3}  99.5
                    & \SetCell{bg=lD3}  99.15
                        & \SetCell{bg=l1}   99
                            & \SetCell{bg=l1}   99.1
                                & \SetCell{bg=white}{99.1\TblrNote{\textdaggerdbl}\\2.3}
                                    & \SetCell{bg=l4}   99.2    \\
8 boxes
    & \SetCell{bg=l3}   {85.35\\    2.13}
        & \SetCell{bg=l1}   {85.15\\    2.28}
            & \SetCell{bg=l1}   {79.1\\     2.61}
                & \SetCell{bg=l3}   78.75
                    & \SetCell{bg=lD2}  75.85
                        & \SetCell{bg=lD2}  76.75
                            &  \SetCell{bg=lD2}  76.1
                                & \SetCell{bg=lD3}  76.2
                                    & \SetCell{bg=l3}  76.05   \\
16 boxes
    & \SetCell{bg=l3}   {62.1\\ 4.69}
        & \SetCell{bg=lD2}  {65.2\\ 4.52}
            & \SetCell{bg=l2}   {60.55\\ 5.64}
                & \SetCell{bg=l1}   53.5
                    & \SetCell{bg=l3}   52.75
                        & \SetCell{bg=l2}   52.2
                            & \SetCell{bg=lD4}  49.95
                                & \SetCell{bg=l4}   50.05
                                    &  \SetCell{bg=lD4} 51.55   \\
    \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

from the previous post [How to fill color in table cells with two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/638629/131975)

I would like to make columns (e.g., d=2.5m) a bit wider and separate with vertical lines also wider the parts of Ideal, Simple and Complex.

Definition `\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}` that I have used in other tables does not work with tabulararray environment.

Comment: Add the option `vline{5}={wd=1pt}` (after `vlines`) to change the default rule width of the 5th vline.

Comment: @PaulGaborit It works, thanks. Do you know how to increase the column width e.g., those of d=2.5?.

Comment: Remove `vlines` and change `colspec = {| Q[r] *3{|[1pt] X[c, m] | c | X[c, m]} |},`

Comment: In fact you can also make all columns except the first one `c`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum The vertical lines appear as double-line now with `colspec = {| Q[r] *3{|[1pt] X[c, m] | c | X[c, m]} |},` instead the `vlines`.

Comment: As I said, remove the `vlines` option.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Thanks, you are right, now there is one vertical line between columns. The text inside the cells, some are now at top of the cell.

Comment: Make that `colspec = {| Q[r] *3{|[1pt] X[c, m] | Q[c,m] | X[c, m]} |},` then.